# Where i can find feather algorithm just like "feather" in photoshop?

Tags: algorithm

Where i can find feather algorithm just like "feather" in photoshop?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Where have you looked so far?

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question to me.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.gimpusers.com/forums/gimp-developer/5856-how-to-get-the-code-of-feather-function

It's seems to talk about your search here and so you will have to look into Gimp Sources files. (Gimp is Free...)